# Disable Slackbot spam

Tags: slack, slackbot

I see this spam message from Slackbot often:

> Good news! Slack can now do more with Google Drive files, like help you share files and manage who can see them.

It is "permission spam" when an application begs you to give it access to your credit card/private data/contact list/etc.

How do I disable/mute/stop/ban/silence this spamming slackbot?